# My posts are not rendered if I return them from the function

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am getting data from graph-ql `useStaticQuery`
like this at the start of the function component

```
const blogs = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      allContentfulBlogPost(sort: { fields: publishedDate, order: DESC }) {
        edges {
          node {
            title
            publishedDate
            slug
            tag
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
```

Now I am trying to render the posts I get from the graphql

```
const renderBlogPosts = () => {
    {blogs.allContentfulBlogPost.edges.map((oneEdge, i) => {
      const tags = oneEdge.node.tag.split(" ")
      return (
        <div className="blog__post" key={`blog${i}`}>
          <Link to={oneEdge.node.slug}>
            <h4 className={`title${i}`}>{oneEdge.node.title}</h4>
            <p className="blog__date">{oneEdge.node.publishedDate}</p>
            <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
              {tags.map((oneTag, i) => {
                return <p className="blog__tag" key={`tag${i}`}>{oneTag}</p>
              })}
            </div>
          </Link>
        </div>
      )
    })}
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <form onSubmit={handleSumbit}>
        <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
        <button>Search</button>
      </form>

      <div className="blog__container">
          {renderBlogPosts()}
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
```

As you can see I got `renderBlogPost` function Which will return all the blog posts.

1. The code inside the function components are moved from the component return statement
2. The posts are not rendered if and only if i renders by calling a function.
3. If i move back all the codes back to component return statement the posts are rendered fine

Is this problem related to the graph-ql. Although the posts are not showing i am not getting error log

Comment: You have to return the JSX to `renderBlogPosts` function. Adding `return` keyword before `blogs.allContentfulBlogPost.edges` should fix your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a GraphQL issue, of course, it's because of your code. In your `renderBlogPosts` function you are not returning anything. Just change it to:

```
const renderBlogPosts = () => {
    return blogs.allContentfulBlogPost.edges.map((oneEdge, i) => {
      const tags = oneEdge.node.tag.split(" ")
      return (
        <div className="blog__post" key={`blog${i}`}>
          <Link to={oneEdge.node.slug}>
            <h4 className={`title${i}`}>{oneEdge.node.title}</h4>
            <p className="blog__date">{oneEdge.node.publishedDate}</p>
            <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
              {tags.map((oneTag, i) => {
                return <p className="blog__tag" key={`tag${i}`}>{oneTag}</p>
              })}
            </div>
          </Link>
        </div>
      )
    })
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <form onSubmit={handleSumbit}>
        <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
        <button>Search</button>
      </form>

      <div className="blog__container">
          {renderBlogPosts()}
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
```

Comment: Another question, is getting data from graphql equals to fetching data in  `componentdidmount` ?

Comment: No.  Data fetching with GraphQL + Gatsby occurs in the build time (while running `gatsby develop` or `gatsby build`). Using the `componentDidMount` or `useEffect` hook lifecycles will make the asynchronous call once the DOM tree is loaded.